# how to return a tuple for a constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, stdtuple

After searching for a while, I still can't quite get this. Can someone please tell me how to return a tuple in a constant expression. Here's the code:

```
#include <tuple>
constexpr std::tuple<int, int> ret2 () {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return std::make_tuple(a, b);
}

constexpr int ret1 () {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::tie(a, b) = ret2();
    return a + b;
}

constexpr auto tmp = ret1();
```

clang++ -std=c++14 -o test test.cpp

```
test.cpp:15:16: error: constexpr variable 'tmp' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr auto tmp = ret1();
               ^     ~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:17: note: non-constexpr function
      'operator=<std::__1::tuple<int, int>, void>' cannot be used in a constant expression
        std::tie(a, b) = ret2();
                       ^
test.cpp:15:22: note: in call to 'ret1()'
constexpr auto tmp = ret1();
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:899:9: note: 
      declared here
        operator=(_Tuple&& __t) _NOEXCEPT_((is_nothrow_assignable<base&...
        ^
1 error generated.
```

clang --version

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I have tried changing this to `std::tuple<int&, int&>`, and using `std::ref`, etc... I just can't seem to find the correct sequence.

Also, calling std::get 2x would be verbose in code and possibly wasteful in runtime. Is there some way to get both values through one call - as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `std::tuple::operator=` because it's not `constexpr`. Your example can be converted to:

```
constexpr std::tuple<int, int> ret2 () {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    return std::make_tuple(a, b);
}

constexpr int ret1 () {
    constexpr auto t = ret2();
    return std::get<0>(t) + std::get<1>(t);
}

constexpr auto tmp = ret1();
```

which does the same as the original, though I'm not sure if it satisfies your real needs.

Comment: `constexpr auto tmp = ret1();` does not directly use any `operator=`: it is an initialization, not an assignment expression.

Comment: I changed the code to show the need for both values. In my real use case, I need both values and they both help to produce the constexpr result.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one call?

Comment: @nachum: updated. anyway it's `constexpr` so it wasn't a big deal to call it twice

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of your `ret1` just needs [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get):

```
constexpr int ret1() {
    return std::get<0>(ret2());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5df9152b807059d).

Comment: I changed the code to show the need for both values. In my real use case, I need both values and they both help to produce the constexpr result.